# What is the use of auth.restTokenPrivateKey in gerrit's secure.config for?

Tags: gerrit, gerrit-trigger, sonar-gerrit

I came across this variable which got generated and stored in secure.config file on gerrit review_site, Is it possible for me to make use of this restTokenPrivateKey value to call rest api to gerrit instance?

Answer (score 0):

[Iff4f6f9a1c302dfd9e2b7fe52f2ddbebe06d9967](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/q/Iff4f6f9a1c302dfd9e2b7fe52f2ddbebe06d9967) removed it. According to the other change referenced there, it was never really used for anything.

The [Authentication section of the REST API docs](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html#authentication) says you can prefix the endpoint URL with `/a/` to use HTTP authentication instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, But when, I try to do that, it fails with following error, `requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='gerritsite.com', port=32611): Max retries exceeded with url: /a/projects/xyz (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x102b44dd8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))`